# How to debug or using Accesibility Inspector for hybrid applications using Electron or Atom

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, accessibility, atom-editor

I'm trying to automate actions, and using macOS most applications are a breeze because of AppleScript and/or System Events, but there's a trend of hybrid applications that don't give me any access to anything, not through AppleScript or Accessibility. The only thing I can extract from Visual Studio Code is the title and the outermost window.

I know they're basically just web wrappers, and with regular websites I can use debugging tools or extensions to extract or change any type of information I want. For example, WhatsApp web allows me to find the user, select it, put text in the text box and then send it.

Are there are options to debug hybrid applications or use accessibility tools to access them? The only thing I found so far is debugging an application I wrote myself with special flags.

Comment: This is the problem when debugging compiled code. AppleScript-savvy apps have exposed methods and publish that API which the AppleScript editor can read. Without that information it wouldn't be able to do anything, which is probably why Visual Studio displays so little. Explaining how it all works is too broad a question. Research how AppleScript works, dig into the examples, and you'll eventually see how it works and why you get so little detail on other apps that don't implement AppleScript.

Comment: Well System Events allows you to get to almost anything in native code, take Xcode's Accessibility inspector and use the crosshairs on a typical native application like Mail. Everything in the UI is targetable without a specific Apple Script implementation. Hybrid applications or platform within a platform stuff like Firefox doesn't allow me to do anything.